# Firefox extension to speed up the playing of youtube videos

Tags: firefox-extensions

I can speed up HTML5 Youtube videos by hand by clicking on the rounded shape (setting of a video) then set it from "Normal" to ex.: 1.5x.

**Question**: How can I set a default play speed to 1.5, so I don't have to do it each time by hand? Can it be done with a Firefox Extension? Or an about:config trick?

Answer (score 0):

Consider taking at look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604934/html5-increase-youtube-speed-2x-from-url

Though they are using javascripts here.

Comment: Just a helpful link to an answer somewhere else should really be done in a comment.  Answers should be self-contained.  Your post would be more useful and the information more permanent if you expand your answer to include the essential information, and use the link for attribution and reference.